# Dynamic Programming Concept: Principle of Optimality

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

My question is from the following slide about Principal of Optimality.

From the description, any sub-path of the optimal solution will be optimal too. But I'm thinking about a case which I think is best understood by the pseudo-code as follows:

```
if (PQ picks a non-optimal route) such that
    AP now can have a much shorter path cost, which leads to the optimal solution.
    This path only emerge when PQ is such non-optimal route.
```

Does my example make the Principal of Optimality a false statement? If not what's wrong with my reasoning?

Or does it mean that DP cannot be applied to these kind of problems?

[image]
[image: Principle of Optimality]

Comment: The only way that a path from P to Q can affect a path from A to P is if the two paths try to use the same vertex R. That would introduce a cycle containing P and R -- but in that case, provided all edge lengths are >= 0, there is a shorter path that cuts out this cycle, so no such path can be shortest-possible.

Comment: Whatever subpath from A to P you're imagining could be shortest, you could follow that subpath and then still follow the optimal path from P to Q, and then the optimal path from Q to B.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: How can you assure that this is always the case? What if there is a kind of problem have this property?

Comment: If there is a different problem which doesn't satisfy the principle of optimality, then that problem would not satisfy the principle of optimality; that's it. But the shortest path problem *does* satisfy the principle of optimality.

Comment: I've updated my comment to hopefully clarify. There are many problems that lack this "non-interference" property, but shortest path has it.

Comment: @kaya3: So only problems that satisfy this property then we can apply DP, and there exists an optimal problem that doesn't satisfy this property?

Comment: A good example of a problem that lacks this property is the *longest* path problem. (Considering only simple paths, i.e., paths that contain a vertex at most once.) The longest path from A to P might share a vertex with the longest path from P to Q, so they can't automatically be combined.

Comment: If you're talking only about optimisation problems, then yes - put another way, dynamic programming can be used for optimisation problems which have [optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure), and it is not generally useful for optimisation problems which do not have optimal substructure. Dynamic programming can also be useful for problems which are not optimisation problems, if they have [overlapping subproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems).

Comment: It's actually always possible to recover the optimal substructure property by breaking the problem up into sufficiently small subproblems. For longest path, if we instead ask for the longest path from A to B *that avoids vertices outside of some given set X of vertices*, we can solve it: It must be, over all vertices C reachable from both A and B, and all ways of splitting X into two sets Y and Z, the longest path AC that avoids vertices outside of Y, followed by the longest path CB that avoids vertices outside Z. The issue is that there are now an exponential number of subproblems to solve.